# How to create dynamic sidebar links in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I am completely new to vue.js and trying to learn how to leverage this framework to build a frontend for my API.  I am using the vue-admin theme and there is a sidebar with some nav links in it, that looks like below.

store/modules/menu/index.js

```
const state = {
  items: [
    {
      name: 'Dashboard',
      path: '/dashboard',
      meta: {
        icon: 'fa-tachometer',
        link: 'dashboard/index.vue'
      },
      component: lazyLoading('dashboard', true)
    },
    charts,
    android,
  ]
}
```

then, in the same directory as index.js I have charts.vue and android.vue.

android.vue

```
import lazyLoading from './lazyLoading'

export default {
  name: 'Android',
  meta: {
    icon: 'fa-android',
    expanded: false
  },

  children: [
    {
      name: 'Jobs on Android',
      path: '/andr/android',
      meta: {
        label: 'android',
        link: 'android/Basic.vue'
      },
      component: lazyLoading('android/Basic')
    }
  ]
}
```

So in my sidebar, I now have 'dashboard', 'charts' and 'android'.  What I can't figure out is how to dynamically create links in my sidebar based on an API request.  the API request will return a simple list and I want to then build the sidebar links from the list.

Would I move the android.vue code back into the index.js and use a for loop to create each link?  I'm guessing everything should be consolidated into a single index.js for this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a main component for the menu that will take care of getting all the links in the store and that will return the array items

```js
// Create this component ./main.vue
//file main.vue

import lazyLoading from './lazyLoading'

/* I presume you have a field named items in your store 
 and it has this architecture : 

items: [{ name: 'Dashboard',path: '/dashboard',meta: {
        icon: 'fa-tachometer',link: 'dashboard/index.vue'},
        component: "dashboard"},
        { name: 'chart',path: '/chart',meta: {
        icon: 'fa-chart',link: 'chart/index.vue'},
        component: "chart"}, ...etc]
*/  
var items = this.$store.state.items 

for (i in items) {
items[i].component = lazyLoading(items[i].component, true)
}

export default items;
```

Then, you can import main.vue and insert it in index.js

```js
//file index.js

import items from "./main"

const state = {
  items:items
}
```

I have not really tested it but I hope it will work and will help you

Comment: I have posted a more specific question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847091/how-to-create-dynamic-links-based-on-api-request